# HAXM driver : incorrect signature (Win 7 - 64bit - core i7)

Tags: android

It's a known issue.
So I've followed all the steps I've found for the installation.

- Verified CPU capability.
- Modified BIOS setup.
- Tried Manual installation.
- Tried this workaround from Intel (https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/04/25/workaround-patch-for-haxm-installation-error-failed-to-configure-driver-unknown)
- Tried the "last chance" at the end of previous article (manually registering the driver via the .inf file).
- Trying all the stpes suggested by the user Reiner.T. in the comment section  (that solved for someone).

But nothing worked for me. Win7 still refuses to start the intelhaxm service ("c:> sc query intelhaxm" reports that the kernel driver status is STOPPED).
Forcing it with "c:> net start intelhaxm" gave me a System Error 577 - "The signature of the driver is incorrect ...." and it doesn't start it.

Why am I so unfortunate ? Why is my Windows configuration so inflexible ? Does anyone know a workaround ?

Thanx in Advance

Marco

Answer (score 0):

Ok I’ll answer to my question.

Starting with Win Vista MS decided to add the “Device Driver Signature Enforcement”  protection to x64 systems so that you can install only MS certified drivers.  To my system the HAXM driver provided by InteI, (an essential component if you want to run the free Android Device Emulator with Android Studio) looks unsigned and the system refuse to load it. I don't know why others don't have the same issue.

To verify if the driver is running type in the Command Prompt (maybe require Run as Administrator):

```
Sc query intelhaxm
```

If the STATUS appear to be "RUNNING" you'va solved the problem. But I always found the STATUS to be "STOPPED".

A not permanent solution could be at boot time to press F8 (F6 or F5 for someone) before Windows Logo appears and, among other choices, to select the one that disable digital sign test for drivers (the bottom one in my Win7). 
Doing so should allow the driver to be loaded. But it’s quite annoying doing it every boot.

A permanent solution is to run Windows in test mode and sign the driver for test mode. To do so I used a small utility named “Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider 1.3b” to sign the file "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\IntelHaxm.sys" and to switch Win7 in TestMode. You can find the utility and all steps description here:
http://www.ngohq.com/?page=dseo

It worked for me but it leaves a small watermark on the desktop saying "Windows 7 Test Mode".

HTH

Marco

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My system is win10 64bit, with Intel(R) Core i7-6700HQ processor. Windows will prevent the installation of the driver that does not match or without Microsoft's digital signature. By installing Microsoft's digital signature for the driver, and restarting the computer, i solved the problem.

How to install the Microsoft's the digital signature for the driver? Follow these steps:

1. open device manager and choose "update driver software for the target",
   first, my English is bad, please forgive me.
2. choose "browse my computer for driver software",
3. choose "let me puck from a list of device drivers on my computer"
   [image]
4. choose a model and click "next": 
   [image]
5. Wait and click ok.

Restart computer and try again `sc query intelhaxm` in cmd.

Since i didn't know which driver is the driver for the HAXM, i used the Microsoft's the digital signature for all drivers.